# Git clone Windows 10 invalid argument

Tags: git, windows-10

I'm cloning a git repository on Windows 10 but there's a directory which name contains a colon. Both sourcetree and git command line shows me the same error: invalid argument. I tried on linux and I could clone it normally, however I need to do it on Windows. There's not an option renaming the directory. 
There's any way to clone the repo on Windows 10?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe with Cygwin, not sure if that would really help circumvent windows issues.

Comment: Clone it with no checkout option and then manually checkout the files/folders you need.

Comment: Thank you @MrTux for your answer. I'm new with Git. I'm cloning using this commanf git clone - n <url>. But then I don't know how to do the second step you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading everywhere, I'm afraid that is not possible to clone a git repository on Windows if a directory or a file has a colon in its name. It's a Windows limitation.

That's frustrating